# Al intentar compilar en Android Studio 1.3 sin conexión

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Al intentar compilar en Android Studio 1.0.1 sin conexión me da este error
y al probar el android studio 1.3 me hace lo mismo.

> Error:Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library' during up-to-date check.  See stacktrace for details.
>
> Could not read entry 'P:\ProyectosVariados\android\Myyyy135\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\AndroidManifest.xml' from cache fileHashes.bin (P:\ProyectosVariados\android\Myyyy135.gradle\2.2.1\taskArtifacts\fileHashes.bin).

No entiendo que puede ser espero me puedan ayudar gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En cuanto al error, en esta parte:

> Error:Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task
> 'prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library'

indica que se tiene un problema con la support library `appcompat-v7:21.0.3`

Te sugiero **conectar a internet al menos en una ocasión** para que pueda descargar las dependencias que necesita, y posteriormente sincroniza el proyecto con los archivos `build.gradle`:

`File` -> `Sync Project with Gradle Files`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este error generalmente se produce cuando precisamente no puede descargar las dependencias, porque no tienes conexión, no tienes credenciales de proxy o algún antivirus que no permite la descarga.

---

Como comentario, si usas  Android Studio 1.0.1, me parece que no algunos componentes actuales no funcionarían correctamente, el problema principal sería Gradle.

Actualmente la última versión [Android Studio es 5.0.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?hl=es-419) , te recomendaría actualizar.